# How can I use three conditions in an IF formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to track training expiration dates and can't quite get the formula to work. Here is what I am attempting to do;

- the spreadsheet is set to update with the current days date
- anytime training is expired using the current date I would like the cell to say "EXPIRED"
- anytime the expiry date is coming up within 90 days of the current date I would like the cell to say "DUE"
- the third condition is that training is not going to expiring within 90 days so the cell should say something like "GOOD"

Am trying to use an `IF` formula within an `IF` formula and just not getting the results as above.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This question is lacking details needed for anyone to be able to help you. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including formulas and how your data is laid out. To create a example table in text, [this site](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) is helpful. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Answer (score 5):

I set up a worksheet like below:

[image]

Using these formulas:

[image]

(and dragging down) it will process the IF THEN you are trying to do.

Remember any IF THEN is structured like this:

```
=IF(condition,if true,if false)
```

That means for a nested it works like this:

[image]

You input what you want the statement to return for the conditions listed by A1, A2, A3.  Take a look at the colors. The green color is used to show the first IF statement, the cyan to show the second. Notice how they are put together.

By the way, today's date is 4/6/2016 when running this. I put the 3 dates to be within the 3 regions.

Comment: Good answer, but can you explain to the OP about nesting the `IF` statement in order to check multiple conditions? I think that would make your answer great.

Comment: The key to this answer is that the "false clause" is another complete "if statement". This is usually called "nesting" or a "nested if"

Comment: @CharlieRB I updated my answer with what I think is a pretty good explanation with colors and such for a nested IF statement